# Unable to get available provider resolvers

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, javabeans

When we use Bean Validation, it is working fine. But after running for some time, there is a RuntimeException:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to get available provider resolvers.
        at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:265)
        at javax.validation.Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory(Validation.java:110)
        at org.dacell.app.order.isale.service.IsaleTradeValidate.validate(IsaleTradeValidate.java:40)
        at org.dacell.app.order.isale.service.IsaleTradeValidate$$FastClassByCGLIB$$15097933.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
        at org.dacell.aspect.ValidateLogAspect.around(ValidateLogAspect.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1869.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

**lib** : hibernate-validator-5.0.1.Final.jar

Answer (score 3):

I got this error from WebSphere. validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar has always been added to the target EAR file. This was never a problem until I changed the class loading strategy to "parent last". I also get this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.bval.jsr303.ApacheValidationProvider incompatible with javax.validation.spi.ValidationProvider

The solution was to remove validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar from the target EAR file by adding the following dependency, which sets validation-api to "provided":

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```